# How can I convert the color in this button into an alpha transparency so that any background will show through, changing the color of the button?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, alpha-channel

The button has a layer in it that has a bevel/emboss filter on it. I'm stumped.

[Here's the PSD that I'm trying to convert](http://files.mattalexander.me/button.psd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the fill of the shape to 0 and added a copy to mask the background. Saved it as a PNG with transparency like this:

[image: like this]

(The button text is transparent, you will see it if you view the image on a black background)

> [PSD file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_TaCHqzrkOwMzlhZDdhNGUtN2ZmMC00Nzc2LWE3ZDEtMGUxYjI4N2ZhZGY4)

From [Reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com/r/photoshop/comments/m15tw/how_can_i_convert_the_color_in_this_button_into/c2x9c2d)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Set the background fill of the button shape to RGB(127,127,127).
2. Set the layer **Blend Mode** to **Overlay**.
3. Open the **Blending Mode** dialog, and play around with **Bevel and Emboss**.

The first 2 steps will make your button shape "see-through."  After playing around with Bevel and Emboss, adding a soft drop shadow and inner glow, I get something like this:

[image]